# copying xampp database or tables into external hard drive or usb stick

Tags: mysql, database, xampp

hey everybody...
I'm running xampp test server on my system. I was wondering if there is any way to copy the database or tables from my system into an external hard drive or usb stick so that i could carry my database wherever i need. If not the records can I atleast store the structure of the database or tables in the form of mysql queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a dump of either:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html